# A webplayer that does not reload (re-stream/re-cache) previously cached video after skipping backwards?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-player

I have sifted through several HTML5 javascript players (i.e. all listed on http://videosws.praegnanz.de/), to select one to use on client's site. All of them are ineffective in the sense that when skipping the video backwards a few minutes/seconds to a segment which has already been played (thus cached in the browser/player), this part gets reloaded from the server, instead just replayed from the cache.
So, is there a webplayer that does not reload previously cached video segment after skipping? I understand this is undoable for 2 hour movies, but I am looking for a player, which can (at least) load a 2 minute long clip, cache it and re-play any part of it from cache (and even if the device goes offline).